# RXPY semaphore filter

Tags: python, rx-py

I'm looking to execute a batch of processes in parallel, but process each batch in series using RXPY (we're using v3 right now).  Each process is kicked off, then I use RXPY to wait for a set amount of time before ending the process.  Here's a basic version:

```
def start_task(value):
    print(f"Started {value}")
    return value

def end_task(value):
    print(f"End: {value}")

def main():
    print("Start main")

    rx.interval(1).pipe(
        ops.flat_map(lambda time : rx.from_([1,2]).pipe(
            ops.map(lambda value: [time, value])
        )),
        ops.map(lambda value: start_task(value)),
        ops.delay(2),
        ops.map(lambda value: end_task(value)),
    ).run()
```

The problem with this is the long-running processes overlap each other.  In other words, I do not want new processes to start before the last batch has finished.  In the above example, the output is:

```
Start main
Started [0, 1]
Started [0, 2]
Started [1, 1]
Started [1, 2]
Started [2, 1]
Started [2, 2]
End: [0, 1]
End: [0, 2]
End: [1, 1]
Started [3, 1]
End: [1, 2]
Started [3, 2]
End: [2, 1]
End: [2, 2]
...
```

As you can see, time 1 and 2 started before 0 ended.

I can solve this by adding a boolean variable `working`, somewhat like a semaphore:

```
def start_task(value):
    print(f"Started {value}")
    return value

def end_task(value):
    print(f"End: {value}")

def main():
    print("Start main")

    global working
    working = False

    def set_working(input):
        global working
        working = input

    rx.interval(1).pipe(
        ops.filter(lambda time: not working),
        ops.do_action(lambda value: set_working(True)),
        ops.flat_map(lambda time : rx.from_([1,2]).pipe(
            ops.map(lambda value: [time, value])
        )),
        ops.map(lambda value: start_task(value)),
        ops.delay(2),
        ops.map(lambda value: end_task(value)),
        ops.do_action(lambda value: set_working(False)),
    ).run()
```

With the following output:

```
Start main
Started [0, 1]
Started [0, 2]
End: [0, 1]
End: [0, 2]
Started [3, 1]
Started [3, 2]
End: [3, 1]
End: [3, 2]
```

But this feels wrong.  Is there an existing operator in RXPY that would accomplish this same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Even in your second solution you don't ensure that the next tasks won't start before tasks from first batch are finished.

To simply test it change `end_task` to:

```py
def end_task(value):
    sleep(value[1])
    print(f"End: {value}")
```

the output results become:

```
Start main
Started [0, 1]
Started [0, 2]
End: [0, 1]
Started [3, 1]
End: [0, 2]
Started [3, 2]
Started [5, 1]
```

It happens because sequence that ended task first continues and sets variable `working` back to false even though `[0, 2]` is still being processed.

#### Solution using threading Lock

If you want you can use `Lock` from [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) package to achieve "more pythonic" way.

Now at the beginning of your sequence you should:

- filter if lock is currently locked. (You don't really need to do this part, but since sequence starts every second and runs for at least 2 seconds, you will have a lot of threads in queue waiting to acquire lock, so if you can filter it out it's just better).
- acquire lock
- group all the elements of sequence and release the lock - to ensure that we release the lock once all the tasks have ended.
- release lock

here is my code modification:

```py
from threading import Lock

def start_task(value):
    print(f"Started {value}")
    return value

def end_task(value):
    print(f"End: {value}")
    sleep(value[1])
    # return interval value
    return value[0]

def main():
    # Initialise Lock
    lock = Lock()
    print("Start main")

    rx.interval(1).pipe(
        # Check if lock is currently locked
        ops.filter(lambda _: not lock.locked()),
        # Acquire lock
        ops.do_action(lambda _: lock.acquire()),
        ops.flat_map(lambda time : rx.from_([1,2]).pipe(
            ops.map(lambda value: [time, value])
        )),
        ops.map(lambda value: start_task(value)),
        ops.delay(2),
        ops.map(lambda value: end_task(value)),
        # Group by interval value to ensure that we release lock when all tasks have ended
        ops.group_by(lambda value: value),
        # Release lock at the end
        ops.do_action(lambda _: lock.release()),
    ).run()
```

Comment: I like the usages of the threading lock... but I'm not sure the group_by does much here.  Maybe it should be grouped by until a certain token count is reached?

Comment: Ah, I was able to accomplish this using a buffer_with_count instead of the group_by.